# How do I resolve GPG NO_PUBKEY errors?

Tags: apt, software-sources, sources

After attempting to update within the command line, the system ends with these errors.

```
Reading package lists... Done                                          
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
E: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>
```

where `<PUBKEY>` is `1F3045A5DF7587C3` in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but on Debian 8... assuming that your skypeforlinux repo is setup in

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list

Use the following to fix it:

```
dpkg -s apt-transport-https > /dev/null || bash -c "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https -y" 
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add - 
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list 
sudo apt-get update
```

You should then be able to install skypeforlinux.

Hope this help resolve your issue.